# How can I allow resizable() to increase size beyond initial size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Is there a way to decouple css's `max-height` and `max-width` from the limits used by JQuery-UI's `resizable()`?

I have a div that, when initially created, should be limited in size:

```
.my-div {
  max-width: 40em;
  max-height: 50%;
}
```

I want it to be resizable beyond its initial size, but unfortunately `resizable()` seems to use these attributes to also determine the maximum size for resizing. Trying to override that by passing [`maxHeight` and `maxWidth` options](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-maxHeight) doesn't work. Is there a way to solve this, or some other-work around that will allow me to limit the initial size of the div and later on allow it to increase via `resizable()`?

I've found [an identical question on jquery.com](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/resizable-maxwidth-and-maxheight-options-vs-css-maxwidth-and-maxheight), but it's unanswered there.

[A small reproducing **jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yzn5pnhn/1/) - how can I allow resizing the div to see the ".com" suffix, while keeping only the "stackoverflow" word visible at first?

Comment: Doesn't the obvious way [overriding the properties on the element itself] work for you? From the description provided sounds like it should http://jsfiddle.net/1zf769mn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just implementing the "maximum" logic on the div manually to limit its size, instead of relying on `max-width`:

```
if ($div.width() > limit) $div.css('width', limit);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yzn5pnhn/2/

Comment: This is equivalent to just adding it to the html: `<div style="width:90px;">`

Answer (score 0):

<s>Did you try resetting CSS values via jQuery (not tested) ?</s>

```
$(".my-div").css({
     "max-width": "60em", 
     "max-height": "75%"
 });
```

---

Update :

From you fiddle, I tried this :

```
.my-div {
    width: 90px;
    max-width: 130px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Could it solve your problem ?

Comment: Tried, this also affects the initial div size.

Comment: Sorry, cannot provide a better answer. Maybe could you try to create a fiddle ?

Comment: I can't do that this way, because I want the div to be dynamically sized based on its content (and just limited, via max-). I guess I can iterate over all its content, calculate the resulting width, then set it manually, which basically mimicking what the browser does. I'd prefer a simpler way.